# Correct usage for "tu penses bien que ... !"

Tags: usage

In conversation, I heard my colleague say:

> Il se trouve qu’elle et moi, on envisageait alors de partir étudier au Japon. Alors, **tu penses bien que** quand on a appris la nouvelle, ce n'est pas tombé dans les oreilles de sourdes !

I'm not entirely sure  when and how to use this (perhaps emphatic) expression myself. I wonder if it is similar to "Figure-toi que ..."?

---

***UPDATE:***

I wonder if "vous vous doutez bien que" has a similar meaning to "vous pensez bien que"?

Comment: It's an emphatic, in English:  You ***do*** realize or  you do know or you do imagine. Whether you use realize, know or imagine depends on the context. Also, you ***can*** imagine....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tu penses bien que* pourrait dans ce contexte être remplacé par ***comme tu t'en doutes***. Dans cette phrase, le locuteur fait allusion au fait que son interlocuteur le connaît personnellement, et qu'il est capable de deviner sa réaction.

> ***Comme tu t'en doutes [parce que tu me connais bien]***, quand on a appris la nouvelle, ce n'est pas tombé
>   dans les oreilles de sourdes !

***Figure-toi que*** n'a pas exactement le même sens. Cette expression est plutôt utilisée pour insister sur quelque chose, pour l'accentuer. Par exemple :

> - J'ai vu le voisin tout à l'heure, il ne m'a pas dit bonjour.
> - J'ai vu le voisin tout à l'heure, et bien *figure-toi* qu'il ne m'a même pas dit bonjour !

Comment: Merci. Si on part du principe que son interlocuteur connaît déjà ce voisin assez bien pour cerner le personnage, le locuteur peut aussi dire : « J'ai vu le voisin tout à l'heure. ***Tu penses bien qu***'il ne m'a même pas dit bonjour ! », c’est ça ?

Comment: @Alone-zee Exactement. Notons qu'il y a une pointe d'ironie dans cette phrase, sous-entendu "*comme à son habitude, il était impoli !*". Je pense que cette ironie se remarque plus à l'oral, le ton joue beaucoup.

Comment: « J'ai vu le voisin tout à l'heure, et bien ***figure-toi qu***'il ne m'a même pas dit bonjour ! » Dans cet exemple, la locution « figure-toi que », c'est donc presque l'inverse de « tu penses bien que ». Car le locuteur, ne s’attendant pas à ce que son interlocuteur connaisse déjà ce voisin, est sur le point de lui faire part de quelque chose d’étonnant.

Comment: @Alone-zee Je ne sais pas si l'on peut dire que c'est l'inverse de « tu penses bien que » ; mais je pense que tu as cerné l'idée : le locuteur s'apprête à dire quelque chose d'étonnant, et renforce/accentue ce qu'il va dire en s'appuyant sur « figure-toi que [...] ».