# L'expression « ce n'est pas tombé dans les oreilles de sourdes », c'est une litote ?

Tags: litote

L'une de mes collègues m'a dit :

> Il se trouve qu’elle et moi, on envisageait alors de partir étudier au Japon. Alors, tu penses bien que quand on a appris la nouvelle, **ce n'est pas tombé dans les oreilles de sourdes** !

Cette expression ne m’est pas inconnue, mais maintenant que j'y pense, l'emploi de la négation « ne … pas » laisse penser qu'il ne s'agirait peut-être pas d’une litote qui signifie : « On s'est saisies de l'occasion impatiemment attendue dès qu’elle s'est présentée ! », à plus forte raison que la locution emphatique « tu penses bien que ... » se trouve au début de la phrase.

Comment: « Ce n'est pas tombé dans les oreilles **d'un sourd** » est beaucoup plus courant, mais ça ne change bien sûr rien au sujet de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre Salut. Auquel cas, ce ne serait pas plutôt « ce n'est pas tombé dans ***l’oreille*** d'un(e) sourd(e) » ? Plus précisément, en partant du principe d’***une oreille par personne***  ? Même si la tentation est grande de penser que chaque personne en a bel et bien une paire...  Quant à « ce n'est pas tombé dans ***les oreilles*** de sourdes », si on doit utiliser « oreilles » au pluriel, c’est seulement parce qu’il s’agit là de ***plusieurs personnes*** « sourdes », me semble-t-il.

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai, Ce qui sonnait mal à mon oreille ;-) c'était « de sourdes ». Oreille est beaucoup plus souvent au singulier dans cette expression, peut-être parce qu'une chose ne peut pas tomber dans deux endroits en même temps, qui plus est situés à l'opposé l'un de l'autre.

Comment: @jlliagre Hi. « Il ***n’a pas manqué de*** me rappeler ça. » Do you think this one too is  a form of litotes? With an emphatic meaning: "he ***did make a point of*** reminding me of that." or "he ***made sure to*** remind me of that"  rather than the more literal, neutral "he ***didn’t fail to*** remind me of that."

Comment: Yes, another litote indeed. The sentence never literal.

Comment: @jlliagre Hi. "C'est ***non sans joie*** que ...": This is a litotes too, I take it? :) Is it like "C'est avec grand plaisir que ..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je suppose qu'il s'agit de la suite de [notre discussion dans ta précédente question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26990/13109). Tu as bien fait de poster une autre question, c'est plus pratique pour étendre la réponse qu'en commentaire !

---

Pour moi, il s'agit bien d'une litote. Dans cette phrase, je ne vois aucune ambiguïté, la seule compréhension possible est bien que dès qu'elles ont appris la nouvelle, elle se sont précipitées sur l'occasion.

On aurait tout à fait pu écrire :

> Il se trouve qu’elle et moi, on envisageait alors de partir étudier au Japon. Alors, tu penses bien que quand on a appris la nouvelle, **on a tout de suite saisi l'opportunité** !

La phrase aurait conservé le même sens.

Comment: Merci. Le « tout de suite ! » m’a tout l’air du mot-clé ici, l’idée qui figure ***implicitement*** dans la litote « ce n'est pas tombé dans les oreilles de sourdes ».